# Phase plots of solutions for repeated eigenvalues

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I have a question with respect to phase plots of repeated eigenvalue cases. For instance suppose that one is given a matrix with the following:

$$\overrightarrow{y'} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -4 \\ 1 & -1  \end{pmatrix} \overrightarrow{y}$$

whereby the solution yields:

$$\overrightarrow{y} = c_1e^t\binom{2}1 + c_2(te^t\binom{2}1 + e^t\binom{1}0)$$

I understand that it is asymptotically unstable but what I am unclear is the direction and whether one should plot it according to the following two figures

[image]

[image]

How does one distinguish which way the curves come out of the origin from just from analyzing the system ? I am aware that the plot should actually be the 2nd picture but I am not sure why so some help with respect to this technique would be appreciated.

Comment: Much simpler: take a point, say $(0,1)$. At this point the direction field is $(-4,-1)$ and hence the picture looks like the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the $2×2$ matrix $A$ has a repeated eigenvalue $\lambda$ (with $A\ne \lambda I$), we have $$A=B\pmatrix{\lambda&1\\0&\lambda}B^{−1}$$
and
$$\exp(tA)=Be^{\lambda t}\pmatrix{1&t\\0&1}B^{−1}.$$
The sign of $\lambda$ determines whether the flow is inward or outward, while the signs of $\lambda$ and $\det B$ determine the “handedness” of the phase portrait: if the signs are the same, the phase portrait will be similar to the first one pictured; if they are different, it will be like the second. You can see this for yourself by comparing the simple cases $B=I$ and $B=\pmatrix{−1&0\\0&1}$ (the eigenvector lies along the $x$-axis in both cases) using positive and negative values for $\lambda$.

In your case, $\lambda=1$, $B=\pmatrix{2&1\\1&0}$ and $\det B=-1$, so you’ll get the second phase portrait with outward flow.

Comment: Thank you, does the method of following the determinant of $B$ apply to the other cases of spirals and real eigenvalues as well?

Comment: @PutsandCalls It’s actually slightly more complicated than I first wrote (see update). The situation is similar for spiral trajectories, where you have complex eigenvalues $\alpha\pm\beta i$: the rotation is counterclockwise when $\det B>0$ and clockwise when $\det B<0$, with the flow outward or inward depending on the sign of $\alpha$. E.g., if the signs are both positive or both negative, the curves will be the same, but traversed in different directions depending on $\alpha$.

Comment: @PutsandCalls Actually, that suggests another way to remember what the phase portraits look like: in the base case ($B=I$), the flow is either generally clockwise outward or clockwise inward for a repeated eigenvalue, depending on its sign. If the transformation $B$ isn’t orientation-preserving ($\det B<0$), then the picture gets flipped. Similarly, for the spiral (complex eigenvalue) case, the basic flow is counterclockwise, either outward or inward per the sign of $\alpha$, with the picture flipped for a non-orientation preserving transformation.